# jQuery & fullPage.js - Not working in mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, fullpage.js

I am creating a site with the fullPage.js plugin. I got it to work on the desktop browser but it's not working as expected in mobile.

this is my HTML

```
<div id="fullpage">
    <section id="red" class="section"></section>
    <section id="blue" class="section"></section>
    <section id="green" class="section"></section>
</div>
```

and this is my jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#fullpage').fullpage({
       navigation: true,
   });
});
```

while `navigation:true` I can skip (i wouldn't say scroll) to different sections by touching the navigation dots. I can swipe to scroll up from there as seen in this video. it works in the chrome device emulator though

[video of scroll in the works](https://www.dropbox.com/s/cat2auq3zrb8uzk/VID_20171207_122950848.mp4?dl=0)

P.S. I don't think `scrollOverflow:true` would serve my purpose as there is not much content to scroll in the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the problem. it was not with fullPage.js. In my HTML, I included `jquery.slim.min.js` instead of regular `jquery.min.js`

Apparently, fullPage.js only works with `jquery.min.js`

Answer (score 0):

make it your code like this and try with that jquery

```
<div id="fullpage">
    <div class="section">
        <div class="slide"></div>
        <div class="slide"></div>
        <div class="slide"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: that just adds horizontal scrolling. what i need is vertical scrolling in mobile